# why do ubuntu open source packages have gpg key?

Tags: 16.04, apt, gnupg

I understand that `gpg` keys are for "signing" your data as mentioned on their website (https://www.gnupg.org/)

But why then do some open source packages require me to install a gpg key? What is this protecting against?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

Comment: Part of security.  Google apt debian security

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Apt#security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's protecting the package against tampering. The installer verifies that the package signature is valid and made by one of the keys you have configured your system to trust.

When you add a key with apt-key you trust that key to authenticate software. This means that a third party can not supply you a modified package - it validates that the package is made by whoever controls the corresponding private key.

This means that you don't have to trust whoever operates a Ubuntu mirror; you can verify that they are not supplying malware, because they would not be able to sign a package with a key that you trust.

Comment: do you mean "that you don't trust" at the end?

Comment: No, they would not be able to sign with a key that you *do* trust.